# translating website text according to the selected country from dropdown in laravel using Stichoza laravel package and antonioribeiro package

Tags: php, laravel, google-translate, language-translation

i am sorry if it seems strange but i am stuck in a situation which i am explaining below.

Actually i am making a website where user select a country first from dropdown list using [Antonioribeiro package](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/countries) , once they select country and click on "go to country" button and then they can only search businesses in that country and the url generated would be something like: www.abc.com/country_name and then i want to get locale using the above package and then translate the text of the website by using [another package](https://github.com/Stichoza/google-translate-php) and that package needs to put locale to get it working.

How can i achieve this? if anyone did something like that before.

Any help would be really appreciated.

thank you

Comment: This is not directly related to a specific programming problem. Have you written any code to solve this?

Comment: yes i have written code but if someone used the above packages then they can resolve my issue.

Comment: That is now how StackOverflow works. You don't provide a link to a package and hope that somebody will implement it for you, you need to (try to) create it yourself and we'll help you if you get stuck.

Comment: i am trying to implement it myself. i just need to get an idea of how should i achieve it.